# Hilbert Transforms and Analytic signals in signal processing

Tags: complex-analysis, signal-processing

Hilbert transforms are used in signal processing for creating "analytic" signals (see section 4.4 here [https://www.di.ens.fr/~mallat/papiers/WaveletTourChap1-2-3.pdf](https://www.di.ens.fr/%7Emallat/papiers/WaveletTourChap1-2-3.pdf) for example) which are then used for defining things like instantaneous frequencies.

So, if we have a real-valued function $x(t)$ on reals, and its Hilbert transform is $y(t)$, the function $z(t) = x(t) + i y(t)$ is called the analytic signal corresponding to $x(t)$. In some applications, the signal $z(t)$ is used in place of $x(t)$, that is, it is considered a complex valued surrogate of $x(t)$.

I am interested in knowing why this is so.

Also, the expression "analytic" in analytic signal suggests it is somehow related to analytic functions in the sense of complex analysis. I am interested in knowing what the relation with  analytic functions, if any, is.

Thanks.

Comment: With an analytic signal it is easy to find, at any point $t_0$, the envelope, $\left|z\left(t_0\right)\right|$, and the phase, $\mathrm{Arg}\left[z\left(t_0\right)\right]$.  These values cannot be known at a single time instant, using only a single time instant, with only the real signal $x(t)$.

An analytic signal has a one-sided spectrum about DC, so it is not a "real" signal.  I believe the "analytic" here means useful for analysis and synthesis, and not an analytic function in the complex function sense.